# convert IP to hostname

Tags: python, linux

I want to write a python script to convert IP addresses to hostnames. I am using a Linux box.
I don't see this information in whois command. Are there any commands that always give the correct hostnames (as accurately as possible)?

Comment: I think you are confused about the concepts involved.

Comment: edit- sorry I meant hostname !!

Comment: Apart from a python solution, you can also use the `host` command, for both forwards and reverse DNS lookups.

Answer (score 14):

[Socket](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#gethostbyaddr) library has an API to do [reverse DNS lookups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup).

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyaddr("8.8.8.8")
>>> ('google-public-dns-a.google.com', [], ['8.8.8.8'])
```

Keep in mind that not all IP addresses will have reverse DNS entries, not all aliases might be present in the answer to this query etc.

Comment: Is it the reason why am I not getting the domain name when IP being passed as  in above

Answer (score 3):

The closest you're likely to get is [socket.getfqdn()](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.getfqdn).  It incorporates the results from gethostbyaddr().  Pass it an IP address as a string.