# Get Hostname from IP Address

Tags: python, linux, network-programming

My problem is to match IP address to its hostname.

If the IP address is a public IP then a simple `socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)` solves it but 
my problem is with private IP i.e. IP of a network.

How can I get host names from a network IP address? Is there a way to find out hostname or not?

I'm trying to do this on Linux.

Comment: Search the site first. I don't know python but this looks like what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576744/convert-ip-to-hostname

Comment: This question question is also identical: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575760/python-lookup-hostname-from-ip-with-1-second-timeout

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You've already got the Python code required

```
socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
```

What you need is on the infrastructure side of things. To get an internal hostname, you need to query the internal DNS server for the network in question. Larger networks almost always have internal DNS services but some smaller network don't since they rely on other means (direct IP, NETBIOS, Bonjour, etc.) to find various resources.

**TL:DR** : You need to query the internal DNS services for the network in question